# Paypal simple payment button

Tags: paypal, payment

I have an e-commerce solution that calculates totals, tax, and shipping etc and need to process this single value through PayPal.

I am currently using :

This method doesn't allow credit card payments and doesn't seem to do the callback. Is there a simple way to achieve this without all the API interaction of Express Checkout?

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [PayPal Payments Standard](https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/paypal-payments-standard) for credit and debit card payments. It also supports mobile checkout.

Comment: That link is to a non-existent page.

Comment: Sorry @AusS2000. The link was working back then. Here is a different link:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/paypal-payments-standard/